# Calculator in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, mathematics, calculator

I made a calculator in C++. I wanted to ask is this code well written, understandable, and alright.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        // Declares the variable to store the asked value
        int num1, num2;
        char op;
        // Asks the user for the input of numbers and the operation
        cin >> num1;
        
        cin >> op;
        
        cin >> num2;
        // Declares a variable for the answer
        int result;
  // Handles all the conditions of the operation
  if(op == '+') {
    result = num1 + num2;
} else if(op == '-'){
    result = num1 - num2;
} else if(op == '*') {
    result = num1 * num2;
} else if(op == '/') {
    result = num1 / num2;
} else {
    cout << "Invalid values";
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
    // Outputs the result
    cout << "Answer: ";
    cout << result;
    // Ouputs a thankyou message
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout << "THANKS FOR USING THIS";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use a switch instead of the if statements, I guess

Comment: @user Thanks for the reply bro but how does it make my code better is it faster than using If/else or something?g sorry If I might irritate you for a reason but I am newbie.

Comment: Switch can be a bit faster sometimes (although it probably won't matter in such a small program). However, I meant that it might look a bit prettier that way. Also, you don't need to apologize for being a newbie. You're not irritating at all - this site is meant for questions.

Comment: It is bad practice to use `using namespace std;`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more info.

Comment: You should look up the command pattern. Its a step beyond the switch statement.

Comment: It's well-written and understandable, but wrong. It doesn't handle operator precedence or parentheses or unary operators, and to do any of that you wil need a complete rewrite using a standard eression parsing technique,

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Well the guy is a newbie so for him, this stuff is a bit complex at least the program works and I think he has done pretty well as a beginner.

Comment: @NANO agreed -- the implicit "documentation" here is that it only handles simple `a + b` arithmetic. This could/should be added in code documentation or, more usefully for the user, as a kind of usage statement printed after / instead of `Invalid values`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have some suggestions here:

1. Using switch/case instead of if/else looks a little better and slightly faster as also mentioned in the comments.
2. You could definitely work on formatting your code it can be a lot better

Comment: If `switch` is faster than the equivalent `if`, you need to get yourself a new compiler. A good optimizer does not care, and will transform either construct into the most efficient code possible, whether that's a LUT, binary search, or whatever. Therefore, **do not choose between if/switch based on performance, but rather on readability**. Also, *strongly* prefer a switch when there is an exhaustive list of possibilities, and you aim to cover them all.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok alright

Comment: @CodyGray though I use the built-in compiler in visual studio but maybe my PC is slow.

Comment: Unless you extract the computation of the result into a separate function, I advise against using `switch` here because the `break` statements add a lot of visual overhead, and it's too easy to forget a break. Sure, at one point you have to learn it, but in this early phase of programming just stay with the basics.

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes you are totally correct.

Comment: The C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio is outstanding and provides a solid optimizer. I've spent a lot of time looking at disassembly of object code generated by MSVC for various constructs, and I can't think of any cases where I've seen it fail to convert if statements into efficient object code when it would've done a better job with a switch-case statement. (Sometimes it does a poor job with either/both, but that's a different story.) Note that there is both a "debug" and "release" mode; only the latter has optimizations enabled. These modes should be used as the names suggest.

Answer (score 10):

A good next step in your code would be to test edge cases and account for them. A couple things you could improve:

1. Your code does not handle division by zero. If someone puts in `1 / 0` your program will crash. You can check for this and give the user a nice error message
2. Your code does not handle integer overflow. You'll get interesting results if you try to do `2000000000 * 2000000000` because an `int` can only hold so large of a value.

Comment: I thought div by 0 is UB? But maybe that's only C? Still should check it of course (though maybe not needed for floating point arithmetic).

Comment: @Pryftan It is UB but on any realistic platform today it will most likely crash. With floating-point numbers it's usually positive infinity.

Answer (score 5):

**Switch/Case over if/else**

I think it would be great if you use switch/case instead of if/else it also makes you code look neat. Something like this

```
switch(op)
    {
      case '+': result = num1 + num2;    break;
      case '-': result = num1 - num2;    break;
      case '*': result = num1 * num2;    break;
      case '/': result = num1 / num2;    break;
      default:
          cout << "Please enter valid operation" ;
    }
```

Moreover, using switch/cases over if/else improves computational time when doing multiple iterations.

**Add an OFF button**

Also, the physical calculators that we use are always 'ON' unless they are turned off by pressing an 'OFF' button (or get turned off if no key is pressed for time \$t\$). You can also add that feature.

**Instruction: type of input expected form user.**

Say, a friend of yours wants to run the code, or you are an app developer and your client do not know anything about programming, and he just double-clicks on `calculator.exe` file, it would be great if you can also mention a short note when the program begins telling what logical operations and input format is expected from the user.

**Showing error message**

When someone types in `num1 / 0`. You can either show the error message

```
cout << DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR << endl;
```

Or simply say the answer in Infinity. And its value is

```
#include <limits>
// ...

double a = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

You do not need to show this value, just in case if you want to take this code further and add some more features like 'memory' like our typical calculators.
Note: this is not real infinity! It just a number such that \$a>b\,\,\forall b\$. There is more about [Handling the Divide by Zero Exception in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-the-divide-by-zero-exception-in-c/). Perhaps, I have given only a short glimpse sticking with minimal code policy.

Comment: Oo Thank you very much for this wonderful example.

Comment: What do you mean by “this is not real infinity”? It is a bit configuration that means infinity, and is treated as such by all floating-point operations. Just like NaN is a bit configuration that indicates NaN, and 0 is a bit configuration that indicates 0, and 2.25 is a bit configuration that indicates 2.25, ...

Comment: @CrisLuengo some infinities are bigger than other infinities! The infinity defined here is same as other infinities. Check yourself `if(inf*inf > inf) std::cout << "Hell yeah! Some infinities are greater than other infinities \n";` This is the reason I was critical about that note.

Comment: @KartikChhajed: if that tests positive, it is a compiler-dependent result, maybe caused by some optimization? IEEE defines exactly one representation for infinity, and infinity should compare equal to itself.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That is the problem! It never test positive. I am not sure if \$\infty\times\infty\$ is greater than \$\infty\$. But, I can't think of other infinity say `inf2` which is greater than `inf`. Because there must exist an `inf2` which is greater than `inf`.

Comment: [Why some infinities are bigger than other](https://aeon.co/essays/why-some-infinities-are-bigger-than-others). What I meant was, `inf` here has few mathematical property of \$\infty\$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Some set that has an infinite number more elements than another infinite set, like happens with real and natural numbers. But even in that case, both sets have an infinite number of elements, there’s only one symbol for infinity in mathematics. Given *x x = y*, if you fill out *x* = infty, then *y* = infty as well. There is no such notion as a larger infinity. The only awkward thing in IEEE floats is that infty==infty, whereas they should really not be comparable. But it’s convenient being able to compare them, and hence they’re comparable.

Comment: I'm **very intrigued** by the *OFF* button.  Would you please elaborate on what you're getting at? It's a curious idea for a program I think at least if the program is only this functionality.

Comment: @Pryftan The code will depend on environment one is using: windows or linux. Either way it will require the use of a library outside iostreams, but on Linux at least you'll definitely have to turn off line buffering on the terminal which is a bit esoteric. For windows it is quite straightforward. One can use `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)` with `#include <windows.h>`. (If one presses escape key, the program will exit.)

Comment: Other very bad way of doing would be, when taking entry of `num1` if someone presses Esc key, which has ASCII value `\033`, a conditional statement will end the program. I have not tried it, but I think it is worst way of doing it. So, if someone has better answer I will delete this.

Answer (score 4):

### Prefer `switch` over `else if`s

Switch will make your code easier to read.

### The variable `result` could be uninitialized

Consider situation where user types in incorrect operator. In this case the result is uninitialized and your calculator crashes.

### Division by zero crashes

### Prefer `\n` over `endl`

The `endl` forces the stream to flush. Instead of

```
cout << "Answer: ";
cout << result;
// Outputs a thankyou message
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "THANKS FOR USING THIS";
```

I would suggest something like

```
std::cout << "Answer: " << result 
    << "\n\nTHANKS FOR USING THIS\n";
```